# Why the length of a collection schema doesn't change after deleting the data in mongodb collection using mongoose?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a schema called "Project" and when I delete its data in my app.js the length of the schema stay same.

I delete it in the following route:

```
router.get("/myprojects/:id/remove", function(req, res){
Project.findByIdAndRemove(req.params.id, function(err){
    if(err){
        console.log(err);
        }else{
      res.redirect("/myprojects");   
    }
});
```

});

but when i get the length of the Project in another page, even after deleting everything, the length doesn't change.

```
<%= user.projects.length %>
```

P.S. I have deleted the whole schema in Mongo but the length still shows the same number!!

Comment: i have updated my answer

Comment: after remove you must refresh the page

Answer (score 0):

Better you try like below

```
router.get("/myprojects/:id/remove", function (req, res) {
    let Project = require('./path/to/Project.js');
    Project.remove({ "_id": req.params.id }).exec(function (err, RemoveStatus) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            console.log("Remove Status---->", RemoveStatus);
            res.redirect("/myprojects");
        }
    });
});
```

It have always worked for me.